# Two different projects on the same system, with different node versions

Tags: node.js, angular, nvm

I work on two different projects. One is using AngularJS, and the packages depend on node v4.2.0. Anything above that node version breaks the application, so basically I am stuck with that version.

Recently I started working on a new application using Angular (6 in particular) and I have installed the latest node version (v8.11.3).

Whenever I switch working on any project during development, I use nvm for windows using the following commands:

- nvm use 4.2.0
- nvm use 8.11.3

The problem is, when I deploy the applications on the server. How can I run the two applications, at the same time, with different node versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are limited to a single server, ideally you would run each application in its own Docker container, keeping node versions isolated.

If this is not an option, you can use the `nvm run` command to target specific versions without switching the node variable:

For your angular app:

```
nvm run 4.2.0 your-angular-app.js
```

For the other app:

```
nvm run 8.11.3 your-other-app.js
```